# Make !=null check

Tags: null

Could you please help me make a !=null check here?

```
public static Integer getUserOpenCasesBasedOnTerritory(String userId) 
{
  return getUserOpenCasesListBasedOnTerritory(userId).size();
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the results into a list which is being returned by `getUserOpenCasesListBasedOnTerritory` and then have a `null` check.

Assuming that it is returning `List<Case>` your code should be something like this

```
public static Integer getUserOpenCasesBasedOnTerritory(String userId) 
{
    List<Case> cases = getUserOpenCasesListBasedOnTerritory(userId);
    return cases !=null ? cases.size() : 0; 
}
```

You can replace `Case` with the return type that is being returned from your method.

Comment: Yes Thanks a lot!)

Comment: Pleased to help !

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Integer getUserOpenCasesBasedOnTerritory(String userId) {

//Return a value when getUserOpenCasesListBasedOnTerritory(userId) is null, say, -1, for example
Integer re_Value = -1; 

if(getUserOpenCasesListBasedOnTerritory(userId)!=null && !isEmpty(getUserOpenCasesListBasedOnTerritory(userId)){
   re_Value = getUserOpenCasesListBasedOnTerritory(userId).size();
}

return re_Value;

}
```

Comment: ERROR - "No apex action available for ABI_CXC_Account360_Helper.getUserOpenCasesBasedOnTerritory"

Comment: What is the content of "getUserOpenCasesListBasedOnTerritory"?

Comment: There are List of Cases

Comment: You can try "List<Case> lstCases = getUserOpenCasesListBasedOnTerritory(userId)". Then check if lstCases.size() == 0

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage [String](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) class method to check if the specified String has white space, empty (''), or null. You can have this if condition and return the results accordingly.

`String.isNotBlank(inputString)` - Returns true if the specified String is not whitespace, not empty (''), and not null; otherwise, returns false.

`String.isBlank(inputString)`- Returns true if the specified String is white space, empty (''), or null; otherwise, returns false.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the response of getUserOpenCasesListBasedOnTerritory(userId) method in a list variable and have not null on the variable.

Something like -

```
    Integer iCount=0;
    List<Case> lstCases = getUserOpenCasesListBasedOnTerritory(userId);
    if(lstCases!= null){
    iCount = lstCases.size();
    }
    return iCount;
```